# Passing an id to other controller

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

```
$job->created_by = $input['created_by'];
```

I want to pass user id in this array which is in other table what should I do?

The field is a foreign key.

When I run this it throws an exception

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452
     Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
     (`freight`.`jobs`, CONSTRAINT `approved_by` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`)
     REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

     (SQL: insert into `jobs`
           (`company_id`, `origin`, `commodity`, `destination`,
            `created_by`, `approved_by`, `date`, `carrier`, `consolidator`,
            `overseas_agt`, `prepaid_fob`, `free_time`, `wt_pcs`, 
            `updated_at`, `created_at`)
           values (2, , , , asdsadasdsad, asdsadasdsad, , , , , , , ,
                   2015-11-26 07:32:02, 2015-11-26 07:32:02)
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize the field as unsigned in the DB Migration.
as:

```
 $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
```

Here user_id is a primary key of another table.
Alter the table and run migration again.
It will work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I did wrong I have to give the id of the user that is currently active the correct way is as follow

```
$job->created_by = \Auth::user()->id;
```